# what is Icc pfofile date time?

Tags: file-format

Please Help me it's very Urgent for me
I uploaded my image to http://regex.info for finding exif information because i need the date the image was taken and it found nothing but Profile Date Time as below :

Profile Date Time :2009:03:27 21:36:31
5 years, 11 months, 20 days, 6 hours, 5 minutes ago

i know that icc profile is about color space used to encode pixel colors but i want to know does Profile date time has to do with the time that image was taken?
and i want to know whether the icc profile can tell that the image was not edited in any software like Photoshop or not?

Answer (score 1):

If your picture is straight from the camera it contains information about your camera exposure flash etc. and time if correctly set on camera.
If it have been through a program it might contain data from that program too.
Try right clicking and choose properties, see tab image.
Screen shots cropped by Shotwell contains only the size.
Some modern cameras and phones also provide GPS coordinates.
There is no story, of which programs have done what to the picture.